# How to use Spring Security RemoteTokenService with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I setup a Keycloak server. Configured the realm and client and so on.
I managed successfully to write a Spring Boot service with "org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter" and secured my RestController. Works like a charm.

But when I try to use Spring Security (without the keycloak specific dependencies) I am stuck.

here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
```

}

This is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/person/**").hasRole("DEMO_SPRING_SECURITY")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {

    resources.resourceId("demo-client");
    RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
        "http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/demo-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect");
    tokenServices.setClientId("demo-client");
    tokenServices.setClientSecret("80e19056-7770-4a4a-a3c4-06d8ac8792ef");
    resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
}
}
```

Now I try the access the server:

1. get an access token (via REST client)
   the decoded JWT looks like this:

> ```
> {
> "jti": "78c00562-d80a-4f5a-ab08-61ed10cb575c",
> "exp": 1509603570,
> "nbf": 0,
> "iat": 1509603270,
> "iss": "http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/demo-realm",
> "aud": "demo-client",
> "sub": "6ee90ba4-2854-49c1-9776-9aa95b6ae598",
> "typ": "Bearer",
> "azp": "demo-client",
> "auth_time": 0,
> "session_state": "68ce12fb-3b3f-429d-9390-0662f0503bbb",
> "acr": "1",
> "client_session": "ec0113e1-022a-482a-a26b-e5701e5edec1",
> "allowed-origins": [],
> "realm_access": {
>   "roles": [
>     "demo_user_role",
>     "uma_authorization"
>   ]
> },
> "resource_access": {
>   "account": {
>     "roles": [
>       "manage-account",
>       "manage-account-links",
>       "view-profile"
>     ]
>   }
> },
> "name": "Jim Panse",
> "preferred_username": "demo-user",
> "given_name": "Jim",
> "family_name": "Panse",
> "email": "user@dmoain.com"
> }
> ```

But I get an AccessDeniedException.

> ```
> 2017-11-02 07:18:05.344 DEBUG 17637 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated:
> ```
>
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@1f3ee7e1:
>   Principal: demo-client; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true;
>   Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=;
>   Not granted any authorities 2017-11-02 07:18:05.348 DEBUG 17637 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter:
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@14032696,
>   returned: -1 2017-11-02 07:18:05.353 DEBUG 17637 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is
>   not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
>
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied

I debuged the RemoteTokenService and found out the  Keycloak responds with the exact same accesstoken. Which is fine. 
But than the `DefaultAccessTokenConverter` tries to read the user roles from a field `authorities` which not exists. And the `OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler` evaluates that the user doenst have any roles. --> access denied

So my question:

What is neccessary to make Spring Security work with Keycloak access tokens?

Comment: Even i am also trying to do same can you please share the code

Comment: @chiranjeevigk pls look at my last answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Via keycloak admin console you can create a token mapper of type **User Realm Role** with claim name "authorities" for your client "demo-client".
Then the access token contains the role names in this attribute and no custom *DefaultAccessTokenConverter* is needed.

Comment: You are right. Awesome. If I would have known that earlier :-D

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution by myself just after formulating this question here. Sometimes it helps to try to express a problem.

The solution is to override the DefaultAccessTokenConverter to teach him how to read the "realm_access" field. Its ugly but it works:

```
@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {

    resources.resourceId("demo-client");
    RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
        "http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/demo-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect");
    tokenServices.setClientId("demo-client");
    tokenServices.setClientSecret("80e19056-7770-4a4a-a3c4-06d8ac8792ef");
    tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(new KeycloakAccessTokenConverter());
    resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);

}
private class KeycloakAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities();
        if (map.containsKey("realm_access")) {
            Map<String, Object> realm_access = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("realm_access");
            if(realm_access.containsKey("roles")) {
                ((Collection<String>) realm_access.get("roles")).forEach(r -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)));
            }
        }
        return new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request(),oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication());
    }
}
```